# imported object is permanently hidden warning by definition of object in Scala Spec

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a spec and then I get a compilation error:

```
 imported `Writer' is permanently hidden by definition of object ZipWriter in package util
 [error] import com.thing.util.Writer
```

I have this object:

```
object Writer
```

and my spec does this:

```
package com.thing.util

import com.thing.util._
import java.io.File

class WriterSpec {
  behavior of "buildFilePath"

  it must "append the compressionExtension to the file" in {
    val files: Array[File] = Array(new File("/some/filepath.someData"))

    val compressed = Writer.buildFilePath(files, "gz")
    compressed must be("/some/filepath.someData.gz")
  }    
}
```

that works but if i try to specifc the Writer in the import statement directly, all fails. What gives?

```
package com.thing.util

import com.gemini.util.Writer
import java.io.File

class WriterSpec {
  behavior of "buildFilePath"

  it must "append the compressionExtension to the file" in {
    val files: Array[File] = Array(new File("/some/filepath.someData"))

    val compressed = Writer.buildFilePath(files, "gz")
    compressed must be("/some/filepath.someData.gz")
  }    
}
```

Comment: The error you quote references ZipWriter, but none of your code mentions that object.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> package com.thing.util
>
> import com.thing.util._
> ```

It never makes sense to import anything (or everything) from your own package in the beginning of the file, all of it is already visible.

> i try to specifc the Writer in the import statement directly, all fails

The message says that because there is already `com.thing.util.Writer`, importing `com.gemini.util.Writer` doesn't do anything, `Writer` in your code still means `com.thing.util.Writer` (and if you need to use `com.gemini.util.Writer`, you'll need to write it out or use renaming imports). Normally it should be a warning, you must be passing the compiler option which turns warnings into errors.

Comment: Your answer references com.gemini.util.Writer, which is a different package from OP and elsewhere in your answer.  Should it be com.thing.util.Writer?

Comment: You missed `import com.gemini.util.Writer` in OP.